# Concurrent processing on main queue during UITableView scroll

Tags: cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have a stopwatch screen in my app.

There is a main label indicating passing time every 100 milliseconds (updates constantly).

Just below that label, in the same ViewController I have a UITableView.

Whenever I'm scrolling the UITableView, the stopwatch labels stops updating.

I've tried using Grand Central Dispatch as follows, but it doesn't work and I didn't expect it would, since it's still two operations running on the same queue.

> ```
> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
> MyTimerObject *t = (MyTimerObject*)notification.object;
>     lblMainTimer.text = t.MainTimerStringValue;});
> ```

So how should I approach this problem?

This all happens within the receiveNotification method of NSNotification, which make me wonder if it's not NSNotification that locks up during the table scroll event and not the label update...

Comment: It's a separate class that hold a bunch of other information relating to the timer. And yes, this other class has a NSTimer which triggers the notification once each interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your stopwatch updating with `NSTimer` or `CADisplayLink`? The issue associated with failure to update while scrolling is generally an incorrect choice of run loop modes.

For example, this will pause while tableview is scrolling.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Whereas this will not:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Bottom line, don't use `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`, but rather use `NSRunLoopCommonModes`, and you may find it continues to run even when scrolling the table view.

Comment: I'm not using either of those and my timer runs in another class. If it will solve the issue, I could always run the timer in the ViewController and use notifications or the like to inform the other class of changes...

Comment: I'd first try the simple fix, examining how you scheduled that timer. If using common run loop modes for timer doesn't fix it, then you might have to get notification out of the process, too, but one step at a time.

Comment: It works, and I'm still using the notification too. Thanks a million! I'll have to do some research on RunLoops now to ensure it has no ill side-affects. Should I remove the time from the loop when I stop it? Or ever?

Comment: Yes, definitely remove repeating timer when you're done with it. It maintains strong reference to the target otherwise (and you can have strong reference cycle).